# How to open specific collapsible panel inside modal by clicking in link

Tags: html, jquery, magento2, alpine.js

How to open specific collapsible panel inside modal by clicking in link I'm trying to make a layered filter modal, but i can not create links to appropriate panels in this modal.

We use alpine.js and magento 2 for this. Here is our code.

It would be great if you could help us

```
    <section x-cloak x-data="{open: false}"
             :class="open ? 'overflow-hidden ' : 'overflow-visible '">
        <div class="border-b border-container-lighter flex pb-6">
        <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
        <button
                @click="open = true"
                class="flex-initial items-center text-sm py-2.5 px-4 rounded-full bg-gray-100 mr-2">
            <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?>
        </button>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>
        <div role="dialog"
             aria-labelledby="modal1_label"
             aria-modal="true"
             tabindex="0"
             x-show="open"
             @click.away="open = false"
             class="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 md:inset-x-auto md:inset-y-0 md:right-0 z-30 flex max-w-full">
            <div class="backdrop"
                 x-show="open"
                 x-transition:enter="ease-in-out duration-500"
                 x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                 x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                 x-transition:leave="ease-in-out duration-500"
                 x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                 x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
                 @click="open = false"
                 aria-label="Close panel"></div>

            <div data-modal-document
                 @click.stop=""
                 x-show="open"
                 x-transition:enter="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                 x-transition:enter-start="translate-y-full sm:-translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-full"
                 x-transition:enter-end=" sm:translate-x-0"
                 x-transition:leave="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                 x-transition:leave-start="sm:translate-x-0"
                 x-transition:leave-end="translate-y-full sm:-translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-full"
                 class="bg-white relative w-screen max-w-md shadow-2xl">
                <div
                    x-show="open"
                    x-transition:enter="ease-in-out duration-500"
                    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave="ease-in-out duration-500"
                    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0" class="absolute top-0 right-0 flex p-2 mt-2">
                    <button @click="open = false;" aria-label="Close panel"
                            class="p-2 text-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-black">
                        <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                  stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-col h-full py-6 space-y-6 bg-white shadow-xl">
                    <header class="px-4 sm:px-6">
                        <h2 id="cart-drawer-title" class="text-lg font-medium leading-7 text-gray-900">
                            <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Filtern und sortieren')) ?>
                        </h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="relative grid gap-6 px-6 py-6 overflow-y-auto bg-white
                        sm:gap-8 sm:px-6 border-container">
                        <div class="w-full">

                            <div class="container block p-4 md:border-0 md:bg-transparent md:py-0 md:px-0 my-6"
                                 x-data="initLayeredNavigation()"
                                 x-init="checkIsMobileResolution()"
                                 @resize.window.debounce="checkIsMobileResolution()"
                                 @visibilitychange.window.debounce="checkIsMobileResolution()"
                            >
                                <div class="block-content filter-content pt-3" >
                                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
                                        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                                            <div class="filter-option my-6" id="filter-<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?>" x-data="{ open: false }">
                                                <div
                                                    class="filter-options-title flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer hover:text-secondary-darker border-container"
                                                    :class="{ 'border-b pb-4': open }"
                                                    @click="open = !open"
                                                    @open-dropdown.window=" open = true"
                                                    @click.away="open = false">
                            <span class="title text-md md:text-base font-light">
                                <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?>
                                </span>
                                                    <span class="">
                                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                                     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                     class="transition-transform transform duration-300 ease-in-out"
                                     :class="open ? 'rotate-180' : ''">
                                    <path d="M19 9L12 16L5 9" stroke="#4A5568" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                          stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="filter-options-content pt-3 hidden"
                                                     :class="{ 'hidden': !open , 'block': 'open' }"
                                                >
                                                    <?= /* @noEscape */
                                                    $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </div>
```

How to open specific collapsible panel inside modal by clicking in link I'm trying to make a layered filter modal, but i can not create links to appropriate panels in this modal.